# Volley's NetworkImageView with images on FTP

Tags: ftp, android-volley, networkimageview

The scenario is: "Have adapters that work for HTTP, been asked to add FTP support" - sounds reasonable.
Is there a way to do it in an equally reasonable timeframe?
Or a similar mechanism/customized Volley library to swap Volley for?

The FTP is password-protected, if this makes any difference.

Tried so far:

- HttpClientStack: `Scheme 'ftp' not registered`
- HurlStack" `libcore.net.url.FtpURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection`
- attempted tunneling through a custom URLonnection (multiple difficulties, like libcore package not being public)
- custom ImageCache that takes FTP handling off Volley's hands (what's the point, really?)

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I've come up with thus far: override `performRequest` to do something completely different for ftp links.
Mind, the code here is bad, it just barely serves my purpose:

```
public class HurlStackFtp extends HurlStack {

    @Override
    public HttpResponse performRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders)
            throws IOException, AuthFailureError {

        String urlString = request.getUrl();
        if (urlString != null && urlString.startsWith("ftp://")) {
            return performFTPRequest(request, additionalHeaders);
        } else {
            return super.performRequest(request, additionalHeaders);
        }
    }


    public HttpResponse performFTPRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders)
        throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
        String url = request.getUrl();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.putAll(request.getHeaders());
        map.putAll(additionalHeaders);
        // UrlRewriter not supported

        InputStream input = getStreamFromFTP(url);
        StatusLine responseStatus = new BasicStatusLine(new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 1),
                /*connection.getResponseCode()*/200, /*connection.getResponseMessage()*/"OK");
        BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(responseStatus);
        response.setEntity(makeEntity(input));
        return response;
    }

    public static InputStream getStreamFromFTP(String url) throws IOException {
        URL parsedUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection cn = parsedUrl.openConnection();
        cn.connect();
        return cn.getInputStream();
    }

    private static HttpEntity makeEntity(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();
        entity.setContent(inputStream);
        entity.setContentLength(inputStream.available());
        entity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream"); // sigh...
        return entity;
    }
}
```